# when to use the various sort methods of NSArray?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

The doco explains what the NSArray sort methods are, but is anyone able to give a bullet point say on when/why you'd use a particular method? i.e. under what circumstances in you code would you use method XXX over method YYY.  For:

- sortedArrayUsingComparator
- sortedArrayUsingDescriptors
- sortedArrayUsingFunction:context
- sortedArrayUsingSelector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Collection Programming Topics: Sorting Arrays](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW5) for more general information. If you're looking at the class reference documentation, be sure to check out the "Companion guides" that are listed for more practical, real-world advice on how the classes work.

Basically, `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` and `sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:` have been around since 10.0/iOS 2.0. They're not as flexible as the other methods which came later.

If you have an array of relatively simple objects, like `NSNumber`s or `NSString`s, you could use `[numbers sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]` to easily sort the objects.

If, on the other hand, you have a more complex model object that has multiple properties, such as `age`, `name`, `date`, `NSSortDescriptor`s work well. Those were added in OS X 10.3/iOS 2.0. The allow you to do something like first sort by `age`, then by `name`, and then by `date`.